# Wordpress HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a problem with my webpage, I have host my webpage in Hostalia, and I made a mistake when I was make some changes on my web and now I can access to this with y url, I need enter by wordpress url but before I don't need.
(before I could access via `http://kowastudio.com` but now only by: `http://kowastudio.com/wordpress/`

I will explain my problem and paste the information that I can see.

When my index.php redirect the webpage to wordpress "wp-blog-header.php" I have an error in this sentences and I dont know where or why:

> [Tue Apr 3 16:50:00 2018] [error] PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed
>   opening required
>   '/var/www/vhosts/39/214463/webspace/httpdocs/kowastudio.com/webspace/siteapps/WordPress-241337/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php'
>   (include_path='.:/php/includes:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/vhosts/39/214463/webspace/httpdocs/kowastudio.com/index.php
>   on line 17

This is the code in my index.php:

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/webspace/siteapps/WordPress-241337/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Now I have two `.htaccess` files:

1. `.htcaccess` that I have in `httpdocs/kowastudio.com`

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress 
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
       RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / 
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
       RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
   ```
2. `.htaccess` that I have in `Wordpress/htdocs`

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress 
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
       RewriteEngine On 
       RewriteBase /wordpress/ 
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
       RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L] 
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
   ```

If I forget something, sorry but you can ask and I will answer.

Comment: I can't actually understand the first part of your question, can you try and re-phrase your question if possible.

Comment: Revert your changes and try again

Comment: @MehdiBounya yes of course, sorry for this, it's a little bit difficult to explain. Okay my problem it's that i made some changes and before made this change iI could enter to my web with out /wordpress (http://kowastudio.com/) but now when I change in wordpress to enter into the web with "http://kowastudio.com/" then "http://kowastudio.com/wordpress/" I have a lot of problems that before I didn't have like "HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: And if you edited any wordpress files, you probably messed up the code. Do what @RiggsFolly suggested.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did and the problem persist. Thank you

Comment: @MehdiBounya  I did and the problem persist. Thanks. I dont know if i need change something in the code of the index.php or what